# remove a specific string from an object in an array

Tags: javascript

i have a data as below;

```
var item = [
  {
    id: 3391396,
    content:
      'D <span class="searchmatch">A</span> (born 17 December 2004) is a swimmer specialized in freestyle swimming. She qualified for the 800m freestyle event of the 2020 Summer',
  },
  {
    id: 49247051,
    content:
      'The footballer <span class="searchmatch">A</span> Demir (born 1979), Macedonian football player <span class="searchmatch">A</span> Irizik (born 1964), Swiss footballer <span class="searchmatch">A</span> Tombak (born 1999),',
  },
  {
    id: 38317336,
    content:
      '<span class="searchmatch">A</span> Selan (born 4 December 1977) is a Macedonian-Turkish stage and screen actor. He was born in Skopje, SR Macedonia, SFR Yugoslavia. He is of Turkish',
  },
];
```

I want to remove every "`<span class="searchmatch">`" and it's correlated "`</span>`" from all of them with split&join || replaceAll method but i couldn't reach all objects with for loop, how can i do it? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, please add the code showing what you tried.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried it with.

Comment: Hi, this is the code;
```
item[0].content.split('<span class="searchmatch">').join("").split("</span>").join("");
```
for loop is the part that i mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to apply a function on all elements of an array. In that function, you can use either use [`String.prototype.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) or a full regular expression to replace those tags.

([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454) on why it's generally a bad idea to handle HTML with RegEx; but in this case, if you can be sure that the tags will always be written exactly that way, and you're not actually parsing anything but simply replacing strings, I think it's OK here!)

```js
var item = [{id: 3391396,content: 'D <span class="searchmatch">A</span> (born 17 December 2004) <span class="searchmatch">is</span> a swimmer specialized in freestyle swimming. She qualified for the 800m freestyle event of the 2020 Summer', },{id: 49247051,content: 'The footballer <span class="searchmatch">A</span> Demir (born 1979), Macedonian football player <span class="searchmatch">A</span> Irizik (born 1964), Swiss footballer <span class="searchmatch">A</span> Tombak (born 1999),', },{id: 38317336,content: '<span class="searchmatch">A</span> Selan (born 4 December 1977) is a Macedonian-Turkish stage and screen actor. He was born in Skopje, SR Macedonia, SFR Yugoslavia. He is of Turkish', },];

item.map(i => {
  // if you can be sure that there will never be any other </span> tags in the content
  //i.content = i.content.replaceAll('<span class="searchmatch">', '').replaceAll('</span>', '');
  // otherwise, a regular expression would be the way to go:
  i.content = i.content.replace(/<span class="searchmatch">(.*?)<\/span>/g, '$1');
  return i;
});

console.log(item);
```